# Excel vlook up not blank multi values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I would like to get the first value (for a given key)from the vlookup that is not blank.

```
1   A       1   A
2           2   C
2   C   =>  3   B
3   B       4   W
4   W           
4   X
```

Is it possible with vlookup or do I have to use INDEX, MATCH, CHOOSE etc?
If so can anyone provide an example? I cannot add extra columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula, it looks for the first non blank:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$6)/(($A$1:$A$6=D1)*($B$1:$B$6<>"")),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($D1;$A$1:$B$6;2;FALSE)=0;VLOOKUP($D1;$A$1:$B$6;2;TRUE);VLOOKUP($D1;$A$1:$B$6;2;FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `IF` in an intermediate column, then use this intermediate in your `VLOOKUP` formula:

This gives, using an `extra_tab` if you can't insert columns in current sheet

```
    Sheet1             extra_tab
    A   C   D   E      A     B
    -------------      ---------
    1   A   1   A      1     A
    2       2   C            0
    2   C   3   B      2     C
    3   B   4   W      3     B
    4   W              4     W
    4   Z              4     Z
```

To avoid blanks for further calculation Formula in `extra_tab.A1` and  `extra_tab.B1` is:

```
A                B
=Sheet1!B1       =IF(Sheet1!B1="";"";Sheet1!A1)
```

Formula in `sheet1.D1` is:

```
==VLOOKUP(C1;extra_tab!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am afraid it is not going to help, can you provide an example?

Comment: I cannot add extra columns.

Comment: TGK answer looks better then.

Comment: Yep it looks better but I am afraid about efficiency - there are 2 vlookups  per row.

Comment: So you might use a column in an "extra_tab"